# CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806) only on 3G/4G (Not on Wifi)

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, amazon-ec2

I understand this question has been asked in a similar vein a couple of times, but this error is only occurring on a 3G/4G connection, and not on a wifi connection.

I've also added the appropriate NSExceptionDomains and keys to my info.plist file, as many other answers on here have suggested, and this error does not seem to go away.

I have:

```
NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads = YES
NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = NO
NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = 1.0
NSIncludesSubdomains = YES
```

I am trying to make HTTPS requests to an Amazon EC2 instance (Linux).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed the problem. Turns out I was missing a "www" in front of the URL I was trying to access. The SSL certificate was registered with the "www" in the domain name, and this inconsistency was throwing an error.

This might also explain why the error only occurs on mobile data, but I'm not too clear on the specifics so maybe someone else can explain that.